# Issues while running multiple sites on localhost using XAMP

Tags: apache, codeigniter, xampp, codeigniter-2

I have two codeigniter project accounting.local and acc.local hosted on my localhost using xamp. Both the project accounting.local and acc.local contains the same files(codes). What I am doing at the moment is editing one of the project and checking the changes between the edited and unedited version of the application. The first page of the application is a login page. When logging in from "http://accounting.local" I land up at

```
http://127.0.0.1/accounting/login/home_main
```

and when logging in from "http://acc.local" Instead of logging in to the system, it redirects me to the login page of "http://accounting.local"

```
http://127.0.0.1/accounting/login
```

I expected it to land up at

```
http://127.0.0.1/acc/login/home_main
```

I am not sure where the issue comes from. If someone has similar issues or solutions please let me know. Here are the settings of both the projects:
acc.local/route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['404_override'] = 'login/home';
```

accounting.local/route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['404_override'] = 'login/home';
```

Virtual host settings:

```
    <VirtualHost accounting.local>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/accounting"
  ServerName accounting.local
  CustomLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/accounting/logs/accounting.local.access.log" combined
  ErrorLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/accounting/logs/accounting.local.error.log"

  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/accounting">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost acc.local>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/acc"
  ServerName acc.local
  CustomLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/acc/logs/acc.local.access.log" combined
  ErrorLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/acc/logs/acc.local.error.log"

  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/acc">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Base url settings in application/config.php

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/acc/'; //acc.local
$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/accounting/';//accounting.local
```

The user login controller which is same for both the project. controller/login.php

```
function user_login()
{
    if(isset($_POST['enter']))  //Login button pressed
    {
        $data = $_POST;
        $check = $this->login_model->login_match($data);

        if($check)
        {
            redirect('login/home_main');
            // redirect('login/home');
        }....
```

And the windows system hosts file settings:

```
localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 saseco.local
127.0.0.1 accounting.local
127.0.0.1 acc.local
```

I am not very sure where the problem lies, so I have included the codeigniter settings as well as the xamp server settings.

Comment: Are you using database session? Is not try to use database session. Also you try to set  $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: I  am not to sure this may come in handy for multiple applications http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/managing_apps.html